# $this->Auth->User(); is null

Tags: cakephp

I am new in cake php.
I am using cakephp 3.6.2 in linux ubuntu. 
I use cakephp auth component.
While i give correct credentials it redirect back to the login page otherwise says error message "invalid username and password". 
I debug and check details while i give correct credentials. It Set " $this->Auth->setUser($user);" correctly.
But After redirect " return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());" 
 $this->Auth->User() is Null and it redirects back to login page.

**My Code**

**AppController.php**

```
public function initialize(){   

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
               'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
            ]
         ],
         'loginAction' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']

    ]);}
```

**UserCOntroller.php**

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) { 
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
             debug($this->Auth->User()); //contain user details correctly   
             debug($this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl())); // //contain userdetails correctly 
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

**User.php**

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    if (strlen($password) > 0) {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

I print phpinfo() session is enabled. other projects under the "var/www/html" working properly. But inside this project only session not working.

Comment: Is your session working properly? Does it have persistent or in memory storage?

Comment: check session is working or not and then echo $this->Auth->user()

Comment: If you start a new project go for https://github.com/cakephp/authentication instead. This will become the new authentication implementation in an upcoming release of CakePHP.

Comment: @lifepandia My session is not working properly. I print phpinfo() there session is enabled.inside my app session is not working. my session configuration in app.php " 
    'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php'
    ]" .